# Building Flex Builder projects from commandline

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, ant, build, flexbuilder

I have several Flex Builder projects which depend on each other (both libraries and "applications", i.e. projects which generate an SWF), and want to compile them from commandline. I know there is the `fb.exportReleaseBuild` ant-Task, but unfortunately it doesn't work on Linux and only comes with Flex Builder.

Is there any other way to build those projects, including their dependencies, from commandline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One nifty toolset is [Antenae](http://code.google.com/p/antennae/) which has templates for handling nested project with various library dependencies. It's basically bunch of Ant scripts that provide quite a high level of abstraction to the whole build process.

Comment: I just checked out Antenae and one of the examples it has is a multi-project tutorial. It turns out the build.xml script for this still contains "an ordered list that is used to encode the project build order that should be used" which still puts the onus of dependency ordering on the developer/build engineer instead of being programmatic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the command line compiler in the Flex SDK.  [More info](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/compilers_01.html)

Comment: This doesnt't handle dependencies between projects, or did I miss something?

Comment: A Project is a Flash Builder "Creation" and has no real relation to the command line compiler.  Look at properties such as external-library-path, path-element, include-libraries, includes, library-path, runtime-shared-libraries, and source-path.

Comment: Yes, my question probably wasn't precise enough. There are about ~20 projects which depend on each other. When using the command line compiler, I would have to specify the dependencies again. I instead want to use the dependencies listed in the '.actionScriptProperties'-file of a Flex project (the fb.exportReleaseBuild ant-task does this).

Comment: Maybe you need to look into config files for the comand line compiler? http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_22.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use command line to compile flex projects. But you will have to enter the commands manually. Alternatively you can use ant build. Ant is available for GNU/Linux as well. Or which ever build you are comfortable with.